# How to resolve "scanned from multiple locations" warnings caused by jersey

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Google App Engine project that I'm building with maven. I added jax-rs to it by adding the following bom to my pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
            <version>0.73.0-alpha</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Also I needed these three dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion><!-- Exclude this repackaged javax.inject. -->
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion><!-- Exclude this repackaged javax.inject. -->
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see I have excluded some of the repackaged to get rid of some runtime warnings about duplicate classes being found. To be clear, every rest call using the jax-rs api's works fine and I don't see the warnings on google app engine itself, just locally. (full code at https://github.com/Leejjon/blindpool) When running it on the local jetty runtime using 'mvn appengine:run', it still complains about every json related class in the javax.json-1.1.jar and javax.json-api-1.1.jar.

Example

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-12-11 22:01:13.495:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:main: Unknown asm implementation version, assuming version 393216

[INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-12-11 22:01:13.780:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp551734240-15: javax.json.Json scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///C:/Users/Leejjon/IdeaProjects/Blindpool/backend/target/blindpool-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.1.jar!/javax/json/Json.class, jar:file:///C:/Users/Leejjon/IdeaProjects/Blindpool/backend/target/blindpool-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.1.jar!/javax/json/Json.class
```

When I look at my 'mvn dependency:tree' output I can see that my 'jersey-media-json-binding' dependency has both javax.json-1.1 and javax.json-api-1.1 in it. And they have classes that have the same names.

```
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-binding:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse:yasson:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.json.bind:javax.json.bind-api:jar:1.0:compile
```

Full dependency tree (https://pastebin.com/JfwzavDX).

I have tried to exclude them but failed to do so in a way that didn't cause me to actually break my web app and get errors like:  javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

TLDR: What dependency to I exclude here to get rid of the duplicate location warning thrown by the 'mvn appengine:run' command without breaking the jax-rs application.

Hoping for that jax-rs/maven/jetty/jersey/google app engine god to pass by and point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Please, execute ```mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose```